# pip command issue - Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-7n_jim1n/mysql-python/

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, terminal

I am using MACos Terminal, and unable to install mysql on python.

```
pip3 install mysql-python
```

The directory '/Users/aligrdas/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/aligrdas/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

> Collecting mysql-python   Downloading
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
>   (108kB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 159kB/s 
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "/private/tmp/pip-build-7n_jim1n/mysql-python/setup.py", line 13, in 
>           from setup_posix import get_config
>         File "/private/tmp/pip-build-7n_jim1n/mysql-python/setup_posix.py", line 2,
>   in 
>           from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
>       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-7n_jim1n/mysql-python/

Answer (score 1):

As per PEP 8 standard `ConfigParser` has been renamed to lower case as `configparser` in Python 3 and package you are trying to install is not updated yet or may be does not support it.

try using following command:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

check if `mysql-connector-c` is installed on your system if not use following command:

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

working solution for question:

```
1) brew unlink mysql-connector-c 
2) brew install mysql 
3) brew link mysql-connector-c 
4) sudo pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-R1Dazz/mysqlclient/

Comment: sh: mysql_config: command not found EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-qVwv3A/mysqlclient/

Comment: use `brew install mysql` and `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin` and then above command

Comment: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-install-dvgCAv/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 54, in get_config
        libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
      File "setup_posix.py", line 12, in dequote
        if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
    IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: try with flags on `LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib pip install mysqlclient`

Comment: 1) brew unlink mysql-connector-c 2) brew install mysql 3) brew link mysql-connector-c 4) sudo pip install mysqlclient Thank you , it has worked!!!